# Awk - field separator behavior

Tags: awk

I have a file:

```
CreateSec,explorer.exe,\\WINDOWS\\system32\\verclsid.exe,SUCCESS
```

I want to print **"$2"**

**Example 1**

It works well:

```
$ awk -F '\\\\\\\\' '{print $2}' file
WINDOWS
```

**Example 2**

It works well:

```
$ awk -F '\\\\'+ '{print $2}' file
WINDOWS
```

**Example 3**

Does not print.

```
$ awk -F "\\\\\\\\" '{print $2}' file
.
```

**Example 4**

So it works well:

```
$ echo "CreateSec,explorer.exe,\\WINDOWS\\system32\\verclsid.exe,SUCCESS" | awk -F '\' '{print $2}'
WINDOWS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ echo "CreateSec,explorer.exe,\\WINDOWS\\system32\\verclsid.exe,SUCCESS" | awk -F "\\" '{print $2}'
WINDOWS
```

Questions:

1. Why 3 example does not work?
2. How to properly save 3 example?
3. What is the difference between?:

   a) `awk -F '\\\\\\\\'`

   b) `awk -F "\\\\\\\\"`

Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding (3) — four backslashes is the difference:

- Inside single quotes, there are no metacharacters, so the shell passes 8 backslashes to `awk`.
- Inside double quotes, the backslash escapes the following character, so the shell passes 4 backslashes to `awk`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I know that I can save the example 3 as follows --> `awk -F "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" '{print $2}' file`